# how to get values from different classes on click with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

how to get values from different classes with jquery. I made on click to edit and delete, I want to get the idUser value and username and be accommodated using jquery then it can be passed on to the controller, but the values cannot be retrieved and onclick cannot run like a redirect to the next page for editing and there is no action to delete . how can I get values from different classes and onclick can work? I beg for your help, if there is something lacking, apologize and if there is something unclear, you can ask me ...

note: I use php native MVC

This is my code for view table user_management.php

```
    <?php
    $main_controll = new App_UserManagement_Control_UserManagement();
    $data_from_ctr = $main_controll->usermanagement();
    ?>


    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.delete').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        if(confirm("Are you sure want to delete ?")){
            var username = $(this).attr("username");
            var url = $(this).attr("href");
            $.ajax({
                type:'post',
                url: url,
                data:{username:username},
                success: function(data){
                    alert("Data Berhasil dihapus")
                    location.href = '<?php echo BASE_URL. "app.php/usermanagement/user_management "?>';

                },
                error:function(err){
                    alert("Data Gagal Dihapus")
                }
            });
        }
    });

    $('.edit').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var iduser =$(this).attr("iduser");
        var url =$(this).attr("href");

        console.log(iduser);
        //console.log(url);
        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url: url,
            data:{iduser:iduser},
            success:function(data){
                alert(data)
                location.href = '<?php echo BASE_URL. "app.php/usermanagement/edit_user "?>';
            },
            error:function(err){
                alert(err)
            }
        });
    });
});
    </script>

           <fieldset>
         <legend> User Management </legend>  

        <br />

     <span style="font-size: 15px;">
               <a style="text-decoration: underline" href="<?php echo BASE_URL. "app.php/usermanagement/add_user"?>">Add User</a>
     </span>
     <br /><br />
    <table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" border="0" align="left" id="tablecontent">                      
        <thead style="background-color:#eee;">
            <th width="25">#</th>
            <!--<th width="25">id</th>-->
            <th width="80">Username</th>
            <th width="117">Name</th>
            <th width="117">Company Code</th>
            <th width="117">Company Name</th>
            <th width="80">User Access</th>
            <th width="80">Login Status</th>
            <th width="80">User Status</th>
            <th width="200">Action</th>

        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php if($data_from_ctr['user'] !== NULL): ?>
            <?php $i = 1; foreach ($data_from_ctr['user'] as $row):
             ?>
            <!--?php 
            $No=0;
            foreach($data_from_ctr['user'] as $row) {

                $No++;
            ?>-->

            <tr>
            <td><?php echo $i++; ?></td>
            <!--<td><?php //echo $row ['idx'] ?></td>-->
            <td><?php echo $row ['_user'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row ['_fullName'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row ['_pyrCode'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row ['_desc'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row ['group_user'] ?></td>
            <!--<td><?php //echo $row ['_flag'] ?></td>-->
            <td>
            <?php
            $status = $row['_flag'];
            if($status == 0){
                echo "Offline";
            }elseif ($status == "") {
                echo "Online";
            }else{
                echo "Online";
            }
            ?>
            </td>
            <td>
            <?php
            $active = $row ['active'];
            if($active == 1){
                echo "Active";
            }else{
                echo "Non Active";
            }       

            ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                   <a class="edit" href="<?php echo BASE_URL. "app.php/usermanagement/edit "?>" iduser="<?php echo $row ['idx'] ?>">Edit</a>
                    &nbsp;
                   <a class="delete" href="<?php echo BASE_URL. "app.php/usermanagement/delete "?>" username="<?php echo $row ['_user'] ?>">Delete</a>
                    &nbsp;
                    <a onclick="///return confirm('Are you sure want reset {{ row._fullName }} password ?')" href="#">Reset Password</a>
                </td>       
            </tr>
              <?php endforeach; ?>
              <?php endif; ?>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        </fieldset>
```

This is my controller usermanagement.php function edit

```
public function edit(){
    Template::setTitle('Edit User Management');

    $iduser =(int)Request::post('iduser');

    //$idUser = (int)Session::get('idx');

    $result = $this->getUserbyId($iduser);   

    $dataresult = json_decode($result, true);
    if($dataresult === NULL) {
        echo "<script language = \"javascript\">window.alert(\"\Don't Have Data\");";
        echo "javascript:history.back();</script>";
        return false;
    }
    $data = $dataresult;
    return $data;
  }
```

This is My code from controller usermanagement.php delete function

```
public function delete(){

        $username = Request::post('username');

        echo json_encode($username);

        if( !empty($username)){

        $url="http://localhost:8585/delete-user/$username";

        //echo $url; die;

        //$link_url = urlencode($url); 
        $curl = curl_init($url);

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        $result = curl_exec($curl);
        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

        curl_close($curl);

        //Route::redirect(BASE_URL.'app.php/usermanagement/user_management');

        return $result;

        } 

    }
```

This is my controller usermanagement.php function getUserbyId

```
public function getUserbyId($iduser){


        echo json_encode($iduser);

        if(!empty($iduser)){

            $url="http://localhost:8585/get-user/$iduser";

            $curl = curl_init($url);

            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            $result =  curl_exec($curl);

            if($result === FALSE){

                die('Curl failed: ' .curl_error($curl));
            }
            curl_close($curl);
            return $result;
        }
```

This is my page edit_user.php

```
<?php
$main_controll = new App_UserManagement_Control_UserManagement();
$data_from_ctr = $main_controll->edit();
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#level').change(function(){
        var val =$(this).val();
        if(val == '03' || val == '04'){
            $('.limit').show();
        }else{
            $('.limit').hide();
        }
    });


    $('#access').change(function(){
        var val = $(this).val();
        if(val == 'user'){
            $('.level').show();
        }else{
            $('.level').hide();
            $('.limit').hide();
        }
    });

 $('#acctAccessed').chosen();

    $("#chkall").click(function(){
        if($("#chkall").is(':checked')){
            $(".chosen-select option").prop('selected', true);
        }else{
            $(".chosen-select option").prop('selected', false);
        }
        $(".chosen-select").trigger("chosen:updated");
    });
    $(".chosen-select").chosen();
});

</script>

<form method="POST">
<fieldset>
    <legend> Edit User Management </legend>
    <table border="0" width="700" id="usermanagement">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="160"><strong>Company</strong></td>
            <td width="10">:</td>
            <td width="193" colspan="2" class="company"><span class ="id_company"><?php echo Session::get('pyrCode'); ?></span> <?php echo $data_from_ctr['account']['desc']['desc'];?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td width="150"><strong>Username</strong></td>
            <td width="10">:</td>
            <td colspan="2">
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="<?php echo $data_from_ctr['user']['_user']; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="150"><strong>Email</strong></td>
            <td width="10">:</td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $data_from_ctr['user']['email']; ?>" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td width="150"><strong>Status User</strong></td>
            <td width="10">:</td>
            <td colspan="2">
           <input type="radio" name="status_active" value="<?php echo $data_from_ctr['user']['active']; ?>"  checked="" id="aktif"/>
                    &nbsp;Active
            <input type="radio" name="status_active" value="<?php echo $data_from_ctr['user']['active'];?>" id="nonaktif" />
                    &nbsp;Non Active
            </td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="150"><strong>Name</strong></td>
            <td width="10">:</td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo $data_from_ctr['user']['_fullName']; ?>" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td width="150"><strong>Phone Number</strong></td>
            <td width="10">:</td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="<?php echo $data_from_ctr['user']['_noHP']; ?>" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="150"><strong>Access Control</strong></td>
            <td width="10">:</td>
            <td colspan="2">
            <select id="access" name="access">
                <option value="user">User</option>
                <option value="admin_bank">Admin Bank</option>
                <option value="admin_client">Admin Client</option>
            </select>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd level">
            <td width="150"><strong>Level</strong></td>
            <td width="10">:</td>
            <td colspan="2">
            <select id="level" name="level">
                <option value="01">Inputer</option>
                <option value="02">Verificator</option>
                <option value="03">Authorize 1</option>
                <option value="04">Authorize 2</option>
                <option value="05">COPS</option>
            </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
                <tr style="display: none" class="odd limit">
                <td width="150"><strong>Limit Transaction</strong></td>
                <td width="10">:</td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="text" name="limit" value="<?php echo $data_from_ctr['user']['limit']; ?>" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="150"><strong>Account Access</strong></td>
            <td width="10">:</td>
            <td colspan="2">
            <select id="acctAccessed" name="acctAccessed[]" multiple="multiple" class="chosen-select" style="width:350px;" data-placeholder="Select account">
            <?php foreach ($data_from_ctr['account']['account'] as $data) :?>    
            <option value="<?php echo $data['id'] ?>"><?php echo $data['_giro_OB']; ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
            <input id="chkall" type="checkbox" >Select All</input>
        </td>
            </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td width="150">&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
            <td colspan="2"><input class="btnsubmitdis" type="submit"  value="Save" /></td>
        </tr>


    </tbody>
    </table>
</fieldset>
```

This is my code edit.php

```
<?php
$ctr = new App_UserManagement_Control_UserManagement();
$ctr ->edit();
?>
```

This is my problem:
I have get a data idUser
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWrer.png)

but when I click ok, I want to redirect page edit_user.php
but show this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7Yxh.png)

I want if I click edit show this page
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQNqp.png)

Comment: Where you face difficulty in the above code? On passing required data to ajax end point?

Comment: yess... I can't not get values data from `<a class= "edit">` and `<a class="delete">` can you help me? @Ajith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an error on your code, I have fixed that now. Please see the below code. I have added console.log to debugging the value and it does work for me. Please check and let me know If you face any difficulties

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.delete').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        if(confirm("Are you sure want to delete ?")){
            var username = $(this).attr("username");
            var url = $(this).attr("href");


            console.log(username);
            console.log(url);

            $.ajax({
                type:'post',
                url: url,
                data:{username:username},
                success: function(data){
                    alert("Data Berhasil dihapus")
                    location.href = '<?php echo BASE_URL. "app.php/usermanagement/user_management "?>';

                },
                error:function(err){
                    alert("Data Gagal Dihapus")
                }
            });
        }
    });


$('.edit').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        var idUser =$(this).attr("idUser");
        var url =$(this).attr("href");
        console.log(idUser);
        console.log(url);


        $.ajax({
            type:'post',
            url: url,
            data:{idUser:idUser},
            success:function(data){
                alert(data)
            },
            error:function(err){
                alert(err)
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You can replace `console.log` with `alert` If you are not familiar with firebug debugging

Comment: @May Please upvote and accept If it helps you, Thank you

Comment: i get data is null.. can you have another way? @Ajith

Comment: I have upload my screen shoot problem above @Ajith

Comment: @May what you got in console.log value ?

Comment: I have done get value idUser, but i can't redirect page to edit_user.php, how can I fix it? when I redirect to the page is show pop up "don't have data", but wen I check in console.log I have get the data iduser @Ajith

Comment: I want when I get this idUser data I want to pass on to the controller to be a variable that can be called at curl, how can I make that data become a variable?
I already put the code above @Ajith

Comment: can you help me @Ajith for redirect page to edit_user.php, because I can't redirect but I have get data??

Comment: @May The logic inside `edit and delete` function is difficult for me to understand. Since you are using a framework, make sure that the corresponding function should `disable rendering of template` and use that function only for processing your data. Also try to send response as `json` with status like `success/ failure` to ajax response. Also make sure to include `dataType as json` in your ajax call

Comment: my delete is okey, but delete I have get data iduser but i can't redirect to page edit_user.php, I will show you my code above @Ajith

Comment: how, what do you think? @Ajith

Answer (score 0):

I Thik This Example will help you

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <a class="edit"  idUser="1">Edit</a>
    &nbsp;
    <a class="delete" username="Samrat">Delete</a>
    &nbsp;
    <script>
        $('.delete').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();         
            var username = $(".delete").attr("username");
            var useId = $(".edit").attr("idUser");
            alert("UserID : " + useId + " And UserName :" + username);
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have try but idont get data based column, I get data based session login.. can you have another ay? @assaduzzaman samrat?